# Euclidean Geometry, Question involving reflection, Homothety.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, reflection

[image]

So, let's say there is a line $l$ (here it is $XY$) , $A$ and $B$ are random points on one side of $l$, and $A'$ and $B'$ are their reflections across $l$, I need to prove $AB'$, $A'B$ concur at $l$

Now, I was reading a solution to a problem which I couldn't solve when the author said that this is obvious, as I was low on confidence at that time, I couldn't see it at all, even though this seems completely trivial, so I tried to prove it

I have just learned Homothety, so this was my proof;

let $AB'$ intersect $A'B$ at $O$

Taking a homthety at $O$ which sends $A$ to $B'$

It will send $A'$ to $B$

And hence, it must send $P_1$ to $P_2$

Hence, $P1-O-P2$

Now, I have a couple questions,

**Is this proof correct?

Can you please tell me a normal proof (without homothety)**

Sorry for such a trivial question, idk why I am not able to think :(

Comment: 1) You might want to add more explanation for why "it must send $P_1$ to $P_2$, esp if you're new to homothety. Yes it seems obvious, but what's the evidence? (There are several ways we can substantiate this) 2) Coordinate geom (with XY as the x-axis) works directly.

Comment: @CalvinLin , Would this work; As $OAA'$ and $OBB'$ are iscoceles, So, $P1$ and $P2$ are feet of altitude from $O$ and also mid-points, and as AA' maps to BB', the midpoints must map to themselves.

Comment: @CalvinLin , also, I am not comfortable at all with Homothety, like I understand the definition but I do not "understand" it well (i'm not sure how to explain this), in EGMO, it seems as though homothety has been a bit rushed over, but I know homothety is a very important part of Olympiad Geometry, so could you please suggest me some resources/ tips to learn homothety? Thank you!

Comment: A) Why are $OAA', OBB'$ isosceles? (It is true, but you don't have enough written up as yet to justify it, and I'm not reading your mind).   B) Note: also explain why the homothety sends A' to B.    C) [Here's](https://brilliant.org/wiki/euclidean-geometry-homothety/) a writeup I did for homothethy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof without homothety.

Let $AB'$ intersect $l$ at point $P$.

$l$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AA'$ and $BB'$.

$\angle APX=\angle B'PY$

Hence, $\angle A'PX=\angle APX=\angle B'PY=\angle BPY$ and thereafter points $A'$, $P$ and $B$ are collinear.